# Access Spring Security's FormLoginBeanDefinitionParser's attributes inside AuthenticationSuccessHandler implementation

Tags: authentication, spring-security, servlet-filters

I would like to gain access to form-login tag's configuration properties inside an AuthenticationSuccessHandler implementation.

An example situation would look like the following:

```
@Autowired
private FormLoginBeanDefinitionConfigurationProperties properties;

public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
   String usernameParameterName = properties.getUsernameParameter();
   String passwordParameterName = properties.getPasswordParameter();
}
```

When spring security configuration is configured like so:

```
<security:form-login
            login-page="/login.html"
            username-parameter="the_username_parameter"
            password-parameter="the_password-parameter"
            login-processing-url="/dologin"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"

    />
```

I have tried to inject the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter itself in the authentication handler:

```
@Autowired
private UsernamePassworAuthenticationFilter formAuthenticationFilter;

public class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    String usernameParameterName = formAuthenticationFilter.getUsernameParameter();
    String passwordParameterName = formAuthenticationFilter.getPasswordParameter();     
}
```

But something like that doesn't seem doable since it is reflectively configured via the AuthenticationConfigBuilder and the FormLoginConfigurer and trying to explicitly define this in the application context XML will produce another UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter which has nothing to do with the servlet-context configuration I have set.

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome.